# How to resolve the component session in CCV2?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Context:

In ccv2, with two front-end machines, when the user logs in, the component still has the anonymous session. The session needs to be updated or even force the component's renderer. This is because the content of the product carousel changes depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

Observations:

- Cache flags are disabled.
- It works perfectly in the local
  environment.
- I've tried adding user information in the controller and
  before the handler.
- I've disabled cookies.SameSite.enabled to false.
- I've used this approach: hasAnyRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS').

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with cms.cache disabled on all machines, the solution only worked when I removed the ProductCarouselComponent from cacheKeyProviders

Answer (score 0):

Resolving component sessions in CCv2 can be a complex process and may depend on the specific issue you’re encountering. However, here are some general steps you might consider:

1.Check the logs: The logs can provide valuable information about what’s causing the issue
2.Check your manifest.json file: Errors in your manifest.json file can cause issues with component sessions
3.Customize your buildcallbacks: You can modify the buildcallbacks to customize (add/modify) any Out Of The Box (OOTB) file, either completely or part of it

If you’re still having trouble, it might be helpful to reach out to SAP support or consult the SAP community for more specific guidance

Comment: Even with cms.cache disabled on all machines, the solution only worked when I removed the ProductCarouselComponent from cacheKeyProviders

Answer (score 0):

The default cache key provider for ProductCarouselComponent is the `cmsCacheKeyProvider` which is by default an alias for the `defaultCmsCacheKeyProvider`. This one doesn't consider the current user when generating the cache key. That means that the cache holds the first rendered version of a ProductCarouselComponent. If the first rendering was done for an anonymous user, every user on that appserver sees the anonymous version of the ProductCarouselComponent.

If the content of your ProductCarouselComponent is depending on the current user, the entry for the ProductCarouselComponent should be replaced with the `currentUserCmsCacheKeyProvider`. This would make the current users uid a part of the cache key and the cache would hold a different version of the rendered component per user. Be aware that this can drastically change size and/or hit/miss ratio of the cms cache depending on the size of the cache and the traffic on your shop.

Enabling/disabling the cms cache in the HAC configuration can take up to one minute, because the configuration value is cached in `DefaultCmsCacheService`. By default it is disabled in `acceleratorcms/project.properties`. I suspect that it is disabled on your local development environment and that disabling the cache on the cloud env didn't have an effect immediately.

Comment: The solution I did involved removing the ProductCarouselComponent from the cacheKeyProviders (workaround).

I will test your suggestion. Thank you very much.